# Ramification points of holomorphic map is a closed subset

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am referring to this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/273269/1162293

I do not see why the argument let us tell that ramification points are a closed subset of $X$. Has someone some more details to give ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f: X \to Y$ is *not* ramified at $x \in X$, then it is a local homeomorphism around $x$. I.e., there is an open neighborhood $x \in U \subseteq X$ s.t. $f|_U$ is a local homeomorphism. Hence $f$ is unramified at *all* points of $U$.

That shows that the complement of the ramified points is open.